# How to draw at PictureBox from another Thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a `Form` and a `PictureBox` that located on it. I want to draw some kind of a background in this `PictureBox` (just array of dots that located at specific order) when my `PictureBox` is updating. Code for drawing works fine, but it's take so much time(cause i'm drawing so many dots) and i can't works normally with that form, cause program is waiting till all the dots will be drawned. So i decide to draw this dots at the separate Thread, like this:

```
private void flowchartDrawingArea_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Thread thread = new Thread(() => DrawBackground(sender, e));
    thread.Start();
}


private void DrawBackground(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    GridBackground.GetAreaSize((Control)sender);
    GridBackground.Draw(e);
}
```

And my drawing class looks like this:

```
class GridBackground
{
    /*...*/
    public void Draw(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        int positionWidth = 0;
        int positionHeight = 0;

        while (positionHeight < PanelHeight)
        {
            while (positionWidth < PanelWidth)
            {
                Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(positionX, positionY, R, R);
                e.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.White, rectangle);
                e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(new Pen(Color.Gray, 2), rectangle);
                positionWidth += DotInterval;
            }
            positionHeight += DotInterval;
            positionWidth = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

but i always have a "parameter not valid" exception at "e" at `e.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.White, rectangle);` string. I read that this happens when trying to do something with form controls from other thread, but i don't know how to solve it in my case.

Comment: "*How to draw at PictureBox from another Thread?*" you cant, you need to do it on the main thread. However, you can manipulate bitmaps from with another thread, and update it all at once (on the UI thread)

Comment: You may draw on a bitmap then set it to PictureBox. This is working like DoubleBuffer.

Comment: Put a lock in the 2nd while loop.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement

Comment: Every drawing must happen in the UI thread.

Comment: @MichaelRandall thank you for your comment! So i have to draw small bitmap first, and then, because my background just have rows and rows of the same bitmap, i need to repeat this already drawned bitmap in the loop and paste it to big bitmap, and in the end, in the UI thread just set this big bitmap as a background for my PictureBox, am i understand you right?

Comment: Yeah it seems like this approach would work best, do all your drawing in an bitmap (possibly in another thread if you need it), and then when its done, update your picture box

Comment: @LouisGo thank you for your comment! I tried to do like that, and paste it.So at first i have to draw small bitmap , then, because my background just repeating itself, i need to repeat this already drawned bitmap in the loop and paste it to big bitmap, and in the end, in the UI thread just set this big bitmap as a background for my PictureBox, am i right?

Comment: @jdweng thank you for your comment! Looks like it doesnt working well in my case :(

Comment: @TaW thank you for your comment! Now i will remember this for long, thanks!

Comment: @MichaelRandall thank you very much! I tried like that, but the problem is that i do like that (draw background) everytime when my PictureBox repainting (like changing form’s size or when i draw something else in the PictureBox), so i put this function in this OnPaint handler, but looks like cause in this function i do like PictureBox.Image = bigBitmap, OnPaint handler call itself, cause i changing the image. So my memory grows so fast. How do you think, how can i solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to defer the drawing to another thread, you can use a back buffer. The basic idea is to do all the rendering to an off-screen `Bitmap`, and after you're done, let the UI thread draw this back buffer on the actual `PictureBox`.

There's plenty of optimizations you can do, too. If your code isn't fast enough to render aesthetic features in realtime, that's a problem for a UI, and delegating the rendering to a different thread is just hiding that problem. For example:

- Instead of doing `FillEllipse` and `DrawEllipse` in a loop, render the ellipse once into a bitmap, and then keep doing `DrawImage` instead. That's going to be *much* faster.
- Respect the regions being redrawn in the `Paint` event handler. You're often asked only for a partial redraw, and you're wasting your CPU always redrawing everything.
- If you need to handle scrolling, try using as much of the existing back buffer as possible. Drawing the backbuffer with an offset will give you the same appearance much cheaper.
- In fact, you can even draw entire rows at once, and multiples of rows. Again, it's much faster to draw three bitmaps than to draw 200 individual ellipses.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! It helps me a lot!
I tried to do as you recommend me, but i have some questions:
1) I tried to draw elipse to bitmap, it works fine, but if i need a rows of rows of same elipse, i just need some loop that will repeat this already drawned bitmap and put it to another bitmap, and in the end i just put this big bitmap that consist all this small elipse bitmaps to PictureBox? Am i understand you right?

Comment: 2) I call my draw method everytime when my PictureBox have Paint event. And in the end of draw action i do like PictureBox.Image = myBigBitmap. And looks like this equitent action also count as PictureBox modifying, so looks like im enter to infinite loop that always call event handler. So because of that memory growing so fast and increase till 0.5-0.8 GB. How do you think, how can i prevent this?

Comment: 3) And how to draw only areas that have been updated? Maybe you can send me some links where i can read about that. That would return me so much speed back! Cause, honestly, i also never realise why i should redrawn the whole area, if only small part has been changed :)

Comment: 4) And can you please recommend me to read something about scrolling and back buffer too? I would be very grateful.

Comment: @Donchan Either don't do it in the `Paint` event, or don't use `Image = bitmap` - you can draw a bitmap using `e.DrawImage`. Also, you don't need to keep creating new bitmaps - only change the bitmap when you have to (e.g. when the picture box is resized). As for partial redraws, the basic idea is simple - the paint event handler gives you the area that needs to be redrawn, and you only need to draw the ellipses within that area to do a proper redraw. In general, people don't really do things like this much anymore - this is really low level, and you can find more high level solutions.

Answer (score -2):

Is flowchartDrawingArea your pictureBox name?
You can try this code.

```
Thread thread = new Thread(() => flowchartDrawingArea.BeginInvoke(new Action<object, PaintEventArgs>((o, args) => { DrawBackground(o, args); }), sender, e));
thread.Start();
```

Comment: So you're advice is to start a *thread* and immediately *marshaling* everything back to the *UI thread*? This is an inefficient way of achieving nothing...

Comment: Or you can try BackgroundWorker?

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But looks like this one doesn’t working in my case :(